# CPU-Optimized or Memory-Optimized server do I need?

Tags: vps, hardware

I have a crawler written in Go that I would like to move from my computer into a cloud server. Therefore I am searching for a cloud service and I see that most droplets, instances, etc... have memory and cpu optimized solutions. Which one do I need if my script:

- Uses Go's concurrency feature heavily
- Makes a few thousands of http
  calls in every second
- Makes a lot of simple add/mul/sub operations in
  for loops which are looping through arrays
- Reads global variables
  stored in memory

Answer (score 0):

Just measure what your application stack is actually doing/using - there's no one-size-fits-all, only you can see what it's doing and then provision your new server/s appropriately.

Comment: I am quite not familiar with these kind of measurements. Possibly could you link any articles which tells about the concepts of what should be measured? Or just should I simply check the performance stats during run?